# SharePoint Permissions - Repeated Login Boxes

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a SharePoint site that is locked down through standard Windows permissions.

I keep getting an repeated login box prompt, and it appears that it has to do with the Themes images and the CSS style sheets.

[image]
<sub>(source: [oscommerce-ssl.com](http://www.oscommerce-ssl.com/OGS_Authorization_Issues.png))</sub>

Where do I need to update permissions so that these files have the same permissions as the rest of the site and the user only needs to login once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which is a web inspection tool, you can actually determine which *domains* the rejected requests are attempting to access. As [Kinjal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375498/sharepoint-permissions-repeated-login-boxes/395005#395005) mentioned, it is possible that some of the images, css, or javascript requests are attempting to access through the ip, and not through the domain name.

[MacGyver's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375498/sharepoint-permissions-repeated-login-boxes/382123#382123) option is possible, although that merely masks the problem, in that the multiple domains (or ways of accessing the same domain) are still being requested, but you are hiding it by caching the credentials that are to be used. This solution is also inadvisable if you are the one who is developing the solution, or administrating the farm, as you (usually) cannot possibly apply this hotfix to *all* the machines in your network.

The permissions possibility (as [Øyvind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375498/sharepoint-permissions-repeated-login-boxes/393998#393998) points out) should also be verified, by checking which files are being rejected, and then verifying that the App Pool user has access to each of those locations.

Answer (score 0):

If your running Windows XP the following should solve your problem.

Try setting your network passwords using Stored User Names and Passwords app.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306992

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have manually copied source files to the 12 hive folders. open the file in Windows Explorer, and verify that it has the same (NTLM) security settings as the other files in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case that you are getting prompted 2 (two) times, it could be that first time it is with the IP address and second time it is with the server name.